# Sorting associative arrays/object in javascript/jquery by the length of their values (longest to shortest)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

What would be the best way to sort an associative array/object using javascript/jquery by the length of their values? Longest value to shortest value, if the value is the same then alphabetical.

eg result:

```
     name["mike"]    = "Sanders"
     name["mary"]    = "Smith"
     name["sharon"]  = "Chan";
     name["Xu"]      = "Wang";
     name["John"]    = "Ho";
```

I have looked and looked and could not find a similar question.

Thanks

Comment: An object is an unordered collection of items, you cannot sort it. Which output are you looking for? Maybe something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/W3pbQ/

Comment: @A.Wolff - yes like that, but longest to shortest as per my example output. I realise there is no inbuilt way of sorting. Thanks.

Comment: Oh ya, sorry http://jsfiddle.net/W3pbQ/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var name= [];
name.push({ key: 'mike', value: 'Sanders' });

name.sort(function(a,b) {

   var aVal = a.value.toString();
   var bVal = b.value.toString();
   if (aVal.length === bVal.length) {
     return aVal.localeCompare(bVal);
   } else {   
     return aVal.length - bVal.length;
   }
});



alert(name[0].value); //Ho
alert(name[1].value); //Chan
alert(name[2].value); //Wang
alert(name[3].value); //Smith
alert(name[4].value); //Sanders
```